# How to check order of columns between source and target table in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. i want to compare order of columns between two tables, both tables are having same/different columns and for few order is different. so need to pull out only those column whose order is mismatch. Please help to achieve this requirement in python.

example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0paY.png)

Comment: forgot to mention we have two input ,input1 and input2  when merging these two into signal input via pd.merge ,not getting the expected input ,it is automatically sort the column order.  can we use tuple so that order not changed and then join.                     input1            input2 
src_tbl src_col  tgt_tbl tgt_col
A Col1  A Col2
A Col2  A Col1
A Col3  A Col3
B Col1  B Col1
B Col2  B Col3

Answer (score 0):

To join both inputs, you can use:

```
output = input1.join(input2)
```

Then, you can compute the mismatches:

```
output = output[output['src_col'] != output['tgt_col']]
```

And then add a new column with the `mismatch` tag:

```
output['col_order_check'] = 'mismatch'
```

This gives you your expected output shown in your figure.

Comment: have edit my question .please have a look. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean, but when doing ```input1.join(input2)``` and then use the proposed answers you get your expected output:
```output = input1.join(input2)
output = output[output['src_col'] != output['tgt_col']]
output['col_order_check'] = 'mismatch'```

Comment: I just updated my answer to be coherent with your naming and added the join at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You can do by two lines

```
output = df.loc[df['src_col'].ne(df['tgt_col'])]
output['col_order_check'] = 'mismatch'
```

Comment: forgot to mention we have two input ,input1(src) and input2(tgt) when merging these two into signal input via pd.merge ,not getting the expected input ,it is automatically sort the column order. can we use tuple so that order not changed and then join. input1 input2 src_tbl src_col tgt_tbl tgt_col A Col1 A Col2 A Col2 A Col1 A Col3 A Col3 B Col1 B Col1 B Col2 B Col3